# Differentiability of $\int g(t) f(x+t) f(y+t)dt$ when $g \in C^\infty_c$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $g \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Is the function
\begin{equation*}
h(x,y) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x+t)f(y+t)g(t) dt
\end{equation*}
differentiable in $x$ or $y$. This is similar to a convolution, but we cannot just apply a change of variables to push the derivative on one term so I would suppose this isn't differentiable necessarily without further restrictions on $f$, but I just wanted someone to confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: Should the integral be over $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be differentiable only if the the derivative of f exists in weak sense in required arguments and belongs to $L^1_{loc}$.

Edit: I am sorry I forgot about the other f inside, we might something more even on f like boundedness!